# $router.push refreshing the page and losing data

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a function that calls.

```
 editTrade: function(tradeData) {
    //include index and/or get object from store
    //forward through router.
    this.$router.push({name: '/trading/newTrade', params: {tradeData}})
```

when I hit this endpoint the page refreshes, it displays `/` instead of the intended route and loses all my data so when I do go to the route it is empty.

The URL bar has the correct route but the page is incorrect. I have looked through the docs and you should use `name:` if you are going to send params, I also tried `router.push` as mentioned in a doc but to no avail.

Comment: remove the first / in name might be the culprit leaving the spa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, in my case I could just do it on a button press which was my use case anyway. `b-button` is VueBootstrap. I did change the `name` to a simple string.

```
<b-button
  class="cardButton"
  variant="secondary"
  //This is where the magic happens
  to="{ name: 'newTrade', params: {trade} }"
> Edit </b-button>
```

In the component

```
created () {
        if (this.$route.params.trade){
          //You can use $route.params.trade to access trade.
          this.model = this.$route.params.trade;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to route by its name will only work when the route is named. Make sure the route you're referencing has `name` parameter in routes definition in the Vue Router object.

You can also programmatically navigate to a route by using its path instead of name. In your case it would look like this:

```js
this.$router.push({ path: `/trading/newTrade/${tradeData}` })
```

[Documentation reference](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: I went through a good tutorial and my name was correct, even though it looks like a path, that is what I had in name. I have fixed that anyway to use a simple string. In regards to the params object, your example code does not use that so how are you getting the data into the component? I am using params.

Comment: @illcrx As the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort) says, when providing `path`, `params` option is ignored. Instead to pass route params I inserted them directly into the path as you can see above in the answer's code snippet. Note that the route params and its component props are not the same thing.

Comment: @illcrx I think I can see what you're trying to do. `tradeData` variable is an object, right? If so, you can't pass them over the navigation. You can either: 
a) define ID for your trades' data and pass it as the route param and then in the component fetch the data by its ID;
b) (less pretty and wouldn't recommend it) stringify the data using`JSON.stringify` function and pass it as the route param and then get the stringified data and parse it using `JSON.parse`